# Error de JNI al abrir programa JAVA en otras PC

Tags: java

> **Error: A JNI error has ocurred, please check your installation and try again.**

Cabe acalarar que el error se da al momento de abrir el programa ya con su *"Clean and Build"* en NetBeans, sin embargo, en NetBeans me tira una serie de Warnings y Note pero tengo entendido que no debería afectar el funcionamiento:

```
warning: [options] system modules path not set in conjunction with -source 15
Note: C:\Users\nicol\Desktop\Proyecto interfaz\RegistrosProyect\src\ventanas\Login.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
1 warning
```

He visto que este problema es muy común pero no encontré ninguna solución en concreto que me ayude.

1. Leí que el problema es de versiones con el JDK o Java, sin embargo,
   instalé la mismas versiones que tengo en mi pc y sigue saliendo el
   mismo error.
2. Leí que era porque en mi pc tengo una version de javac diferente a
   java pero no es el caso (lo comprobé en CMD).

Las versiones de java y JDK que tengo son:

**JDK**: 16.0.2

**JAVA**: 8 Update 281

Comment: Java 8 Update 281 = [**JDK8u281**](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/8u281-relnotes.html). ¿O querrás decir el JRE?

Comment: @padaleiana Me referia al JRE que es version 8 Update 281, el ultimo segun Java es el update 301